# How can I check if an imported library is 'used' in a python script?

Tags: python

The title says it all. I am cleaning up python scripts I have written. Sometimes in the writing of scripts I have tried out one library only to replace it, or not use it later.

I would like to be able to check if a library which is imported is actually used within the script later. Ideally i would do this without having to comment out the import line and run it looking for errors each time.

Does anyone know of a resource or script/library which checks for this? Or what about other tips for cleaning up script to share with others?

Thanks, 
Mike

Comment: Pyflakes can do this.

Comment: I'm not sure if the community edition does it, but PyCharm seems to tell me when I have unused libaries (professional edition).

Comment: Thanks ForceBru and selten98, I'll check them both out.

Comment: Write a script to read all your .py files, look for import statements and capture them then search for their use in the text.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a Python linter, they will do this for you, for example `flake8`. Install with `pip install flake8` and run by calling `flake8` in the root folder of your project.

Comment: Thank you, I'll take a look.